# Is there a way to send (by mail) external disks to be installed in azure?

Tags: azure, big-data

We have many TBs of data on external disks (WD passports), and wish to process it using azure's VMs.

Uploading will take forever (and the bandwidth will probably cost too much).

Is there a way to send a package with those passports to an azure data-center, so that they'll be attached as external disks and be usable for VMs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-import-export-service/

Yes, it is possible.

> Hard drives: Only 3.5 inch SATA II/III hard drives are supported for
>   use with the Import/Export service. Hard drives up to 6TB are
>   supported. For import jobs, only the first data volume on the drive
>   will be processed. The data volume must be formatted with NTFS. You
>   can attach a SATA II/III disk externally to most computers using a
>   SATA II/III USB Adapter.

Expect it to cos, though ;) But then, the bandwidth saving are a good argument.